# Custom action brokes the routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I want to add a custom action.

```
  config.actions do
    member :change_status do
      register_instance_option :link_icon do
        'icon-check'
      end
    end
  end
```

But when I restart the server, there is no `rails_admin` routes. I can't see it in `rake routes` as well.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/admin/user"):



Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
  bulk_action POST /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format)       rails_admin/main#bulk_action
change_status GET  /:model_name/:id/change_status(.:format) rails_admin/main#change_status
```

`rails_admin 0.6.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see here https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
  end
end
```

We need to explicitly define `dashboard` and `index` actions in case of adding `actions` block to the `rails_admin` config file.